# EF Core and DI in windows service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use EF Core 2.0 in my windows service application (Targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2). To make things interesting I don't want to just create instance like so

```
DbContext ctx = new DbContext(connectionString)
```

I'd like to use it with dependency injection (StructureMap 4.5.2).

I have a IDbContext and my DbContext looks like:

```
public DbContext(string connectionString): base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options)
{}
```

Reason for my "strange" ctor is that I don't know where or how to configure EF Core in windows service. Where or how do I tell windows service to use connection string in app.config.

What I have done for now is that I tell StructureMap to inject connection string like so:

```
new Container(config =>
{
    // Register stuff in container, using the StructureMap APIs...
     config.Scan(_ =>
     {
        _.TheCallingAssembly();
        _.WithDefaultConventions();
        _.LookForRegistries();
      });

      config.For<IDbContext>().Use<DbContext>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(_connectionString);
});
```

Is there a way to do this similar like in .NET Core MVC app:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Where services is IServiceCollection instance.

Can someone please point me in the right direction how to do this in best possible way?

Answer (score 0):

here is how i do  it..

```
public class RepositoryData : DbContext {

public RepositoryData(string appSettingsOrConnectionName = null) :base(GetConnectionString(appSettingsOrConnectionName ?? "connection"))
{

}

private static string GetConnectionString(string appSettingsOrConnectionName = null)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appSettingsOrConnectionName) && appSettingsOrConnectionName.Contains(";"))
            return appSettingsOrConnectionName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[appSettingsOrConnectionName]))
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[appSettingsOrConnectionName]].ConnectionString;
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[appSettingsOrConnectionName].ConnectionString))
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[appSettingsOrConnectionName].ConnectionString;
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString))
        {
            appSettingsOrConnectionName = "test";
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[appSettingsOrConnectionName].ConnectionString;

        }
        else return _defaultConnString;
}

}
```